# The „create_layout_child“ function is not called in the Layout Manager. GTK4 with C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk4

While trying out the possibilities of the GtkLayoutManager, I tried to use the "create_layout_child" function. According to the documentation, you should create your own instance of GtkLayoutManager for this purpose. "Create_layout_child" should then be overwritten as a virtual function. It will then be called automatically. Accordingly, I've created a derived class from GtkLayoutManager. It's all working now too, but the "create_layout_child" function isn't called, so I can't use it.
Does anyone have an idea or hint on how to implement this feature?

My layout manager looks like this.

```
#include"layout_mywidget.h"

struct _LayoutMywidget
{
    GtkLayoutManager parent_instance;
};

struct _LayoutMywidgetClass
{
    GtkLayoutManagerClass parent_class;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (LayoutMywidget, layout_mywidget, GTK_TYPE_LAYOUT_MANAGER)

static GtkLayoutChild *
layout_mywidget_create_layout_child (GtkLayoutManager *layout_manager,
                                     GtkWidget        *widget,
                                     GtkWidget        *child)
{
    //Function is not called. Why?
    g_print("layout_child\n");
}

/* Container */
static void layout_mywidget_measure (GtkLayoutManager *layout_manager,
                                     GtkWidget      *widget,
                                     GtkOrientation orientation,
                                     int            for_size,
                                     int            *minimum,
                                     int            *natural,
                                     int            *minimum_baseline,
                                     int            *natural_baseline)
{
     /* Already set in widget.ui   */
};

/*Position of the children*/
static void layout_mywidget_allocate (GtkLayoutManager *layout_manager,
                                      GtkWidget         *widget,
                                      int                width,
                                      int                height,
                                      int                baseline)
{
    GtkRequisition label_req;
    GtkRequisition entry_req;
    GtkRequisition button_req;

    GtkWidget *child;

    for(child = gtk_widget_get_first_child(widget);
            child != NULL;
            child = gtk_widget_get_next_sibling (child))
    {
    
        if(strcmp(gtk_widget_get_name(child),"GtkEntry") == 0)
        {
            gtk_widget_get_preferred_size(child, &entry_req,NULL);
            gtk_widget_size_allocate(child,
            &(const GtkAllocation){10,60,200,entry_req.height},-1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(gtk_widget_get_name(child),"GtkLabel") == 0)
        {
            gtk_widget_get_preferred_size(child, &label_req,NULL);
            gtk_widget_size_allocate(child,
            &(const GtkAllocation){width/2-(label_req.width/2),20,
            label_req.width,label_req.height},-1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(gtk_widget_get_name(child),"GtkButton") == 0)
        {
            gtk_widget_get_preferred_size(child, &button_req,NULL);
            gtk_widget_size_allocate(child,
            &(const GtkAllocation){220,60,button_req.width,
            button_req.height},-1);
        }
    
    }
};

/* The default implementation of this virtual function, which means that the widget 
 * will only ever get -1 passed as the for_size value to its Gtk.WidgetClass.measure 
 * implementation. You can overwrite that */
static GtkSizeRequestMode
layout_mywidget_get_request_mode (GtkLayoutManager *layout_manager,
                                  GtkWidget        *widget)
{
    return GTK_SIZE_REQUEST_CONSTANT_SIZE;
};

static void layout_mywidget_class_init (LayoutMywidgetClass *class)
{
    GtkLayoutManagerClass *layout_class = GTK_LAYOUT_MANAGER_CLASS (class);

    layout_class->get_request_mode = layout_mywidget_get_request_mode;
    layout_class->measure = layout_mywidget_measure;
    layout_class->allocate = layout_mywidget_allocate;
    //Function is not called.  Why ?
    layout_class->create_layout_child = layout_mywidget_create_layout_child;
};

static void layout_mywidget_init(LayoutMywidget *self)
{
};

GtkLayoutManager *layout_mywidget_new(void)
{
    return g_object_new(LAYOUT_TYPE_MYWIDGET,NULL);
};
```

[image]